# scala case class put methods in companion object?

Tags: scala, case-class

Is it "cleaner" (resp. better performance) to declare methods in the case class or companion object?

e.g.

```
case class My(a:A) {
    def m(args) = {...}
}
or
object My {
    def m(m:My, args) = {...}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would prefer to put methods in case class. Putting it in companion object sounds like Anemic Domain Model anti-pattern [AnemicDomainModel](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

Moreover you can override case class methods later or extend and mix some traits.

Answer (score 5):

Better to put the methods in the case class; isn't that the whole point of having classes at all? An `object` is static and usually a poor place for methods, as it means they need to take one more argument than they otherwise would. I would expect the method in the class to perform very very slightly better, as there would be no need to load the companion object instance (and more generally, it's closer to the style the JVM is optimized for), but this is almost certainly too small a difference to matter in any real program. Of course no rule is absolute; if you find a particular method seems better suited to the companion object, by all means put it there.